# Exchange Web-Services (EWS) Java Api : 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When I try to connect to the exchange server, i have an 401 error :

```
 microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized
```

I tested with https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ (with same userId, userPw, domain and url) and it works perfectly.

This is my actual code :

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try {
        CustomExchangeService service = new CustomExchangeService(version);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(userId, userPw,domain);
        service.setUrl(new URI(url));
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        service.setTraceEnabled(true);
        Folder.bind( getInstance().service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, PropertySet.IdOnly );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the class CustomExchangeService which this method :

```
protected Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory>     createConnectionSocketFactoryRegistry() {
    try {
        return RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register(EWSConstants.HTTP_SCHEME, new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
            .register(EWSConstants.HTTPS_SCHEME, EwsSSLProtocolSocketFactory.build(
                null, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE
          ))
          .build();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(
          "Could not initialize ConnectionSocketFactory instances for HttpClientConnectionManager", e
      );
    }
}
```

Why do I have this error ? Maybe because of SSL thing ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The error is with the credentials if it was SSL you would get a different error returned. Check your credential format you might want to try just using the UPN as the username then you only need the UserName,Password for the credentials

Comment: Resolved : On the server, open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. Deploy on the left to find EWS. Clic on Authentification and active all lignes with 401.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good question, but i have found another way to solve it!

First, you should import the jar `ews-java-api-2.0.jar`. if you use maven, you would add the following code into your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
  <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Secondly, you should new java class named `MailUtil.java`.Some Exchange Servers don't start `SMTP` service by default, so we use `Microsoft Exchange WebServices(EWS)` instead of `SMTP` service.

MailUtil.java

```
package com.spacex.util;


import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.WebCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.MessageBody;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.net.URI;

/**
 * Exchange send email util
 *
 * @author vino.dang
 * @create 2017/01/08
 */
public class MailUtil {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailUtil.class);



    /**
     * send emial
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean sendEmail() {

        Boolean flag = false;
        try {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1); // your server version
            ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("vino", "abcd123", "spacex"); // change them to your email username, password, email domain
            service.setCredentials(credentials);
            service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.spacex.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")); //outlook.spacex.com change it to your email server address
            EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
            msg.setSubject("This is a test!!!"); //email subject
            msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("This is a test!!! pls ignore it!")); //email body
            msg.getToRecipients().add("123@hotmail.com"); //email receiver
//        msg.getCcRecipients().add("test2@test.com"); // email cc recipients
//        msg.getAttachments().addFileAttachment("D:\\Downloads\\EWSJavaAPI_1.2\\EWSJavaAPI_1.2\\Getting started with EWS Java API.RTF"); // email attachment
            msg.send(); //send email
            flag = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return flag;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        sendEmail();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which works. Only when a call is made to EWS, logging in happens. As I was writing emailValidService for Exchange. I got the same error, i tried for many hours and seeing where is the problem. I used subscribeToPullNotifications() funtion as it calls EWS.

This piece if code wont work if I dont call this.pullEmailNotifications().

```
public  Boolean checkEmailValid(String username, String password, String uri, String  service_name) {
    ExchangeVersion en = ExchangeVersion.valueOf(service_name);
    logger.info("******checkEmailValid service  ************:  "  +en);
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService( en);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(username,password); 
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    logger.info("*** checkEmailValid USERNAME : " + username);
    logger.info("**** checkEmailValid PASSWORD : " + password);

    try {
        service.setUrl(new URI(uri));
        service.validate();
        return this.pullEmailNotifications(service);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        logger.error("login failed : " + e1.getLocalizedMessage());
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}



     @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public  boolean pullEmailNotifications(ExchangeService service) throws 
     Exception {
     try {
          logger.info("pullEmailNotifications");
          List folder = new ArrayList();        


     folder.add(FolderId.getFolderIdFromWellKnownFolderName 
     (WellKnownFolderName.Inbox));
    logger.info("folder creatd : " + folder.size());
    PullSubscription subscription = service.
            subscribeToPullNotifications(folder, 5, null, EventType.Created/* , EventType.Created, EventType.Deleted */);
    logger.info("Adding pull subscription");
    GetEventsResults events = subscription.getEvents();
    for (ItemEvent itemEvent : events.getItemEvents()) {
        logger.info("Event recieved");
        // if (itemEvent.getEventType()== EventType.NewMail) {
        logger.info("New Mail");
        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, itemEvent.getItemId());
        logger.info("Adding message " + message);

    }
    logger.info("Adding pull events" + events);

    return true; 
    }catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("pull notification failed : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```